# Tweak schema of CTAS parquet table in apache drill: make element required instead of optional

Tags: schema, parquet, apache-drill

I'd like to produce a parquet file with a very specific schema using apache drill. I join two tables with CTAS like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE synthetic1 AS (
  SELECT e1.returneddocids AS returneddocids, e1.pathinfo AS pathinfo, c1.counters AS counters
  FROM dfs.`/tmp/tier1.parquet` e1 LEFT JOIN dfs.tmp.shadow3 c1 ON TRUE LIMIT 100
);
```

The resulting file schema looks like this:

```js
message root {
  optional group returneddocids {
    repeated group list {
      optional binary element (UTF8); // need this one as required, not optional
    }
  }
  optional binary pathinfo (UTF8);
  optional group counters {
    repeated group list {
      optional group element {        // need this as required
        optional binary name (UTF8);  // need this as required
        optional int32 value;         // need this as required
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder how can I tweak the CTAS query so `optional` elements above changed to `required`?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite convoluted, you can use [CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA](https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-or-replace-schema/) to apply constraints. In my case this kind of works (not exactly, though could be helpful for others struggling with a similar problem):

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET `store.table.use_schema_file` = true;
ALTER SESSION SET `exec.storage.enable_v3_text_reader` = true;
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA (
  returneddocids STRUCT<`list` STRUCT<`element` ARRAY<VARCHAR>>> NOT NULL,
  pathinfo VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  counters STRUCT<`list` STRUCT<`element` ARRAY<VARCHAR>>>
) FOR TABLE synthetic1;
```